# Iterate over object and to get names

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, iterator

I am trying to iterate over this list and get all the names on the left hand side and assign them to eventName below, any idea on how to go about this?

```
var eventName:String = ?

public static const EVENTTYPE_MAP:Object = {
    'new': 'NEW',
    'trade': 'TRADE',
    'replaced': 'AMEND',
    'cancelled': 'CANCEL',
    'expired': 'CANCEL',                    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var results:Object = yourClass.EVENTTYPE_MAP;
for(var key:String in results){
    trace(key + ": " + results[key]);
}
```

Comment: How would I define results? It is undefined